# VBA Pivot Table dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to create a VBA code for a pivot table whose rows and columns could change in future. I have used below code but I am getting a runtime error 1004 at set ptable stage. I would also like to add a code here delete worksheet "Pivot" if it exists and then create a new one so all data can be captured. Please can you advise.

```
Dim Pivot As Worksheet
Dim pCache As PivotCache
Dim pTable As PivotTable
Dim lastRows As Long
Set Pivot = Worksheets.Add
Set pCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Sheets("CJI Data").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1))
Set pTable = pCache.CreatePivotTable(Pivot.Range("A1"))
```

Thanks,
R

Comment: Hmm, try putting it in `A3`, leaving room for the "pivot filter" area. Side note, `Pivot` is a confusing name for a `Worksheet` variable - I'd probably go with `sheet`, or `pivotSheet`.

Comment: I have tried A3 before but it does not work. I will make the sheet name changes as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need .Address and R1C1?

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create (xlDatabase, Sheets(“CJI Data”).Range(“A2”).CurrentRegion)
```

Also, no need to delete the table if the data expands, that is why you use a dynamic range.  Just refresh the table.

Comment: Then it is most likely your data.  If you do not have a contiguous region in `Sheets("CJI Data")` starting in `Range("A2")` that has column headings and row headings than you will get an error, otherwise the syntax is correct.